# Autologin functionality in java

Tags: java, autologin

I need to provide auto login functionality. I come up with 2 options:

1. save user name and password in file.
2. save user name and password in preferences.

Which option should I take? Which will be better?

Comment: Either way you may as well post the userid and password on a hacker web site. At least think about encrypting the password.

Comment: @James: Thanks for advise I'll encrypt password before saving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both seem viable options. However my vote goes to `Preferences`. Mainly because you would not have to deal with all the checked `IOException`s. The values either exist or don't. In both cases, no exceptions at least.

Do remember to do an encryption/digest of the username/passwords before you save them.